# Angular 2-4: Changing element attribute depending on value other element

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

There are select and input elements in template of a component:

```
<select #dataType
    name="data_type"
    [(ngModel)]="model.data_type">
    <option *ngFor="let t of dataTypes" [value]="t.type">{{ t.name }}</option>
</select>

<input #typeTemplate
    name="type_template"
    type="text"
    pattern="[0-9]+"
    [(ngModel)]="model.type_template"/>
```

Also in component code there is a dictionary like this:

```
const patternsByTypes = {
    'int': '[0-9]+',
    // etc 'data_type' : 'pattern'
}
```

The `patternsByTypes` dict describes a relation between `dataType` select value and pattern of `typeTemplate` input.

How to change `pattern` attribute of `typeTemplate` input if the `dataType` select has changed in compliance with `patternsByType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have ngModelChange event like below:

```
<select #dataType name="data_type" [(ngModel)]="model.data_type" (ngModelChange)="setPattern($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let t of dataTypes" [value]="t.type">{{ t.name }}</option>
</select>

<input #typeTemplate name="type_template" type="text" [pattern]="selectedPattern"
[(ngModel)]="model.type_template"/>
```

**Component**

You need to change your dictionary like below:

```
const patternsByTypes = {
 'int': '[0-9]+',
 //etc
}
 selectedPattern:any;
 setPattern($event){
  this.selectedPattern = this.patternsByTypes[$event];
 }
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's works! But in your solution - 'int': ['[0-9]+'], why here is array? This is typo? May be here should be string like below: 'int': '[0-9]+'?

Comment: @karavanjo, yeah it was my mistake updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make pattern dynamic  by adding square brackets.

```
    [pattern]="model.data_type"
```